# OpenVPN client Selective routing AWS

Tags: openvpn

I am wanting to setup our OpenVPN Clients to selectively route traffic that is bound for AWS and route our internal subnets but let the rest of the traffic leave out the end users ISP connection.

Is also possible to test on my machine before I implement?

Our setup is on a Ubuntu 12.04.5. I am still trying to learn Linux so please understand I do not know where to find the config files if you need them can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, what you describe is quite easy. Just do not configure your clients with the `redirect-gateway` option. I'd suggest giving it a try and then coming back here with specific questions.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. I need to know what to try.

Comment: Find one of the hundreds of OpenVPN tutorials online and give it a try, then come back here with any specific questions you may have.